# Setting up lua_scripts directory for azerothcore docker build

Tags: docker-compose, lua, azerothcore, eluna-lua-engine

I'm running an AzerothCore server for personal access over LAN. I have the server running on docker as per the [setup provided on the official website](https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Install-with-Docker). I've also managed to attach the Eluna lua enging via the [module](https://github.com/azerothcore/mod-eluna-lua-engine) provided on the AzerothCore GitHub.

I can see that Eluna has been successfully compiled with the worldserver, as I get this message following a call to `docker-compose up`:

`ac-worldserver_1  | [Eluna]: Executed 0 Lua scripts in 0 ms`

I also have no problems logging in via a client and playing normally.

Now, the problem I'm encountering is that I cannot seem to find where to place my lua scripts so that they will be used by the server. Digging through config files, I found this parameter in `azerothcore-wotlk/modules/mod-eluna-lua-engine/conf/mod_LuaEngine.conf.dist`:

```
Eluna.ScriptPath = "lua_scripts"
```

This constant is loaded into the main `LuaEngine.cpp` file, so I'm convinced this is the right place to be looking. However, there is no `lua_scripts` directory in the entire repository, including the attached module. I've tried placing it (and a basic `hello_world.lua` script) in multiple subdirectories to no avail. Thinking it might be found outside the repository due to the use of docker, I ran `sudo find / | grep lua_scripts` and found a copy of the folder in this very inaccessible location:

```
/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/3d7f9d1de6602baf9a33ee24333ecdf01d537c2b7b439e90d645ff9643bfdd07/diff/azeroth-server/bin/lua_scripts
```

Obviously this is only accessible via `sudo`, and I cannot easily use this location for development purposes.

As a last resort, I tried changing the `Eluna.ScriptPath` constant to an absolute path in the repository, but this was also unsuccessful. No scripts loaded, no hello world on login. Anyone know where I might look or place the directory?

For reference, the `hello_world.lua`:

```
local PLAYER_EVENT_ON_LOGIN = 3

local function OnLogin(event, player)
    player:SendBroadcastMessage("Hello world")
end

RegisterPlayerEvent(PLAYER_EVENT_ON_LOGIN, OnLogin)
```

Comment: I don't know about LUA and Eluna, however it should not be different than in the classic setup (without Docker)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by binding the `lua_scripts` folder in the `docker-compose.yml` by adding

```
  - type: bind
    source: ./docker/worldserver/bin/lua_scripts
    target: /azeroth-server/bin/lua_scripts
```

in the `volumes` section of `docker-compose.yml`. I put it right under the `worldserver/bin` bind.

Then in `docker/worldserver/etc/mod_LuaEngine.conf` set `Eluna.ScriptPath = "/azeroth-server/bin/lua_scripts"` and put your scripts in `docker/worldserver/bin/lua_scripts`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the docker-compose rework (commit 380f406248bdc1f15227a7b2f8a75b4bf922f730), you should be able to update your `mod_LuaEngine.conf` file to include:

```
Eluna.ScriptPath = "/azerothcore/lua_scripts"
```

and create a `lua_scripts` folder in your base directory (e.g. where docker.compose.yml and `apps/` folder are found).